# How to detect the current running device with Flutter?

Tags: flutter, mobile, analytics

I am developing a Flutter Application and I want to know the current info of the current device running the app programmatically, how can I do that?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

### To get the current Device Info:

You can use the [device_info_plus](https://pub.dev/packages/device_info_plus) package like the following:

```
import 'package:device_info_plus/device_info_plus.dart';

DeviceInfoPlugin deviceInfo = DeviceInfoPlugin();
AndroidDeviceInfo androidInfo = await deviceInfo.androidInfo;
print('Running on ${androidInfo.model}');  // e.g. "Moto G (4)"

IosDeviceInfo iosInfo = await deviceInfo.iosInfo;
print('Running on ${iosInfo.utsname.machine}');  // e.g. "iPod7,1"

WebBrowserInfo webBrowserInfo = await deviceInfo.webBrowserInfo;
print('Running on ${webBrowserInfo.userAgent}');  // e.g. "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:61.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/61.0"
```